# for文と辞書・リストについての質問

Tags: python

Pythonで下記関数を作ると、次のようなエラーが発生しました。

```
alice = {
"name": "Alice", 
"homework": [100.0, 92.0, 98.0, 100.0],
"quizzes": [82.0, 83.0, 91.0],
}

def average(numbers):
    total = float(sum(numbers))
    total = total / len(numbers)
    return total

def get_average(student):
    homework = average(student["homework"])
    quizzes = average(student["quizzes"])
    total = float(0.5*homework + 0.5*quizzes)
    return total

student = alice #test alice
print(get_average(alice))  #correctly works

def get_class_average(students):
    results = []
    for student in students:
        results.append(get_average(student))
    return average(results)

students = alice #test alice
print(get_class_average(students)) #error
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 28, in 
>     File "", line 24, in get_class_average
>     File "", line 13, in get_average
>   TypeError: string indices must be integers

27行目の`alice`を、`[alice]`に変更したらうまく動作するようになりました。

双方を[PythonTutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/live.html) で比較確認したところ、Step 27においてリストが作られるかどうかが違っており、また`alice`の方ではStep 31のfor文実行時に、`get_class_average`の`student`に辞書の文字列キーがひとつ入ってしまっていました。

そこで質問なのですが、どうして19行目では`get_average`が`alice`で動作したのに、28行目の`get_class_average`から呼び出した`get_average`において`alice`では文字列が入ってしまい、うまく動かないのでしょうか。for文に関係していると思うのですが、よくわかりません。

Comment: `get_class_average` は複数のstudentを受けることを想定していてシーケンスでなければなりません。なので、要素が一つでも`[alice]`のようにしなければなりません。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

以下のコードはPython3.3でチェックしています。

次のコードを実行して見れば分かりますが、辞書に対する`for`は辞書のキーの反復になります。

```
alice = {
"name": "Alice", 
"homework": [100.0, 92.0, 98.0, 100.0],
"quizzes": [82.0, 83.0, 91.0],
}
for elem in alice:
  print(elem)
```

従って`get_class_average`の中では文字列に対して`get_average`を呼んでいることになります。さらに`get_average`の中では引数に対して文字列のインデックスを与えています。今回の場合は文字列に対してそのようなインデックスを与えることになるため型エラーが出ています。

```
"mojiretsu"["idx"]
```

->`TypeError: string indices must be integers`

また、`get_class_average`はalice,bob,...のような複数の生徒に対して平均を求めるという意図で書かれている（と思う）ので、`alice`をそのまま`get_class_average`に渡すのではなく、`alice`一人しかいない教室であると考えて`[alice]`としてやるのが正しい関数の使い方でしょう。

Answer (score 0):

get_class_averageがaliceと同じようなキーを持つ辞書型の配列を引数に持つことを想定しているから。